# API to get payment history of a customer

Tags: paypal

I need to show the payment history and balance amount of a customer from paypal account.

It is possible to do by paypal API or we need to maintained the history. If any one knows let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction Search API appears to fit the bill (though you have probably found this by now)...

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_soap_r_TransactionSearch

Answer (score 2):

The user can either enter his own API credentials, or give you third-party permissions to call the GetBalance API call on his/her behalf: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetBalance